# Locale returns locale without a country code

Tags: android, locale

I need to get a country code from default Locale.

```
ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(context.resources.configuration).get(0)
```

It returns locale with language but the country is an empty string.

What is the reason? How do I get country code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578317/get-country-telephonymanager-vs-locale-getcountry

Comment: @Kamer358, yes and it returns an empty string. Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Use this  to get country

```
String locale;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getCountry();
} else {
    locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated in API level 24

Comment: Thank you. I am using practically the same with ConfigurationCompat. 
The problem is that context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry()
returns empty string

Answer (score 0):

> Note:- This is deprecated in API level 24

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

OR

//This will return country code from using his carrier network

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This to get Country code:

```
    String locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getCountry();
    } else {
        locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
    }
```